# Validation Rule for social login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I was trying to implement social login with laravel. Everything seems OK. User can login . But problem is same email with facebook & google + also logged in. So i don't want to let login with same email. How do i implement validation rule for social login? 
Here is the code i i was trying for validation but it throws in `$validator`

```
 public function redirectToProvider($provider)
     {
         return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
     }

    public function handleProviderCallback($provider,Request $request)
    {
        if (!$request->has('code') || $request->has('denied'))
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();     
        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
        Auth::login($authUser, true);      
    }

    public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
    {
        $authUser = User::where('provider_id', $user->id)->first();
        if ($authUser) 
        {
            return $authUser;
        }

    $validator = Validator::make($user->toArray(), [
            'email' => 'max:255|unique:users',

        ]);
    if ($validator->passes())
    {

    return  User::create([
            'name'     => $user->name,
            'email'    => $user->email,
            'provider' => $provider,
            'provider_id' => $user->id,
            ]);
    }
        return Redirect::to('login')->with('errors',$validator->errors()); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really understand your question but i tried to refactor your function

```
public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
{
    $authUser = User::where('provider_id', $user->getId())->first();
    if ($authUser) 
    {
        return $authUser;
    }

   $email = User::where('email', $user->getEmail())->first();

   if (! $email)
   {

    return  User::create([
        'name'     => $user-> getName(),
        'email'    => $user-> getEmail(),
        'provider' => $provider,
        'provider_id' => $user->getId(),
        ]);
    }
    return Redirect::to('login')->with('errors',"Sorry ! This email Already Exists"); 
}
```

Comment: That throws me error like `Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse as array`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the question but here's my guess on what you need.

My Guess: You want to keep email in users table unique.

You can create an additional table to keep records of social login methods named Connected Accounts. Keep basic user info in users table and link the social accounts to the same email record in users table. You give login on the basis of users table and add different social login accounts to connected accounts table.

Users Table

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('lastname')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps(); 
});
```

Connected Accounts Table

```
Schema::create('connected_accounts', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('account_type');
            $table->string('provider')->nullable();
            $table->string('provider_id');
            $table->text('token')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
```

Find or Create user code (if user exists add social login information to connected accounts else create user and add social login information to connected accounts):

```
public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider) {
        $userExists = User::where('email', $user->email)->first();
        if($userExists) {
            $connectedAccount = ConnectedAccount::where('provider_id', $user->id)->first();
            if ($connectedAccount) {
                return $connectedAccount->user;
            }
            else{
                $connectedAccount = new ConnectedAccount();
                $connectedAccount->user_id = $userExists->id;
                $connectedAccount->account_type = 'social';
                $connectedAccount->provider = $provider;
                $connectedAccount->token = $user->token;
                $connectedAccount->provider_id = $user->id;
                $connectedAccount->save();

                return $userExists;
            }
        }
        else{
            $firstName = '';
            $lastName = '';

            if($provider == 'facebook'){
                $name = explode(' ',$user->name);
                $firstName = $name[0];
                $lastName = $name[1];
                $profile_pic = $user->avatar_original;
            }
            else if($provider == 'google'){
                $firstName = $user->user['name']['givenName'];
                $lastName = $user->user['name']['familyName'];
                $profile_pic = $user->avatar_original;
            }
            else if($provider == 'linkedin'){
                $firstName = $user->user['firstName'];
                $lastName = $user->user['lastName'];
                $profile_pic = $user->avatar_original;
            }
            else if($provider == 'github'){
                $name = explode(' ',$user->name);
                $firstName = $name[0];
                if(isset($name[1])){
                    $lastName = $name[1];
                }
                $profile_pic = $user->avatar;
            }

            $uploadedPic = $this->transferProfilePicture($profile_pic);

            $userNew =  User::create([
                'firstname' => $firstName,
                'lastname' => $lastName,
                'username' => md5($user->email),
                'email'    => $user->email,
                'profile_pic' => $uploadedPic,
                'is_verified' => 1
            ]);

            $connectedAccount = new ConnectedAccount();
            $connectedAccount->user_id = $userNew->id;
            $connectedAccount->account_type = 'social';
            $connectedAccount->provider = $provider;
            $connectedAccount->token = $user->token;
            $connectedAccount->provider_id = $user->id;
            $connectedAccount->save();

            return $userNew;
        }
    }
```